# Help identifying this plant

Tags: identification, pruning, plant-care

I have a few of these plants growing in my garden along a trelace fence in the south of the UK. Although I've seen them in my local area grown as more of a mounded shrub.
[image]
[image]

As you can see, the individual branches grow in long thin cane like structures with no discerning taper along their length.

I've never seen it flower or fruit, but it is usually kept trimmed and it seems to train itself up the trelace.

Comment: This looks like Jasminum nudiflorum but it's hard to say for certain without higher resolution images and preferably with a better understanding of its form. Of course, a flower would most certainly result in a positive ID.

Comment: Spot on, if you want to write up as an answer I'll upload some better pictures tomorrow.

Comment: I'm so glad that you're certain that it's J. nudiflorum. I will create a proper answer.

Comment: I believe the ID is right but that plant needs some help; fertilizer for one!  Use Osmocote 14-14-14 to help with foliage and allow flowering.  I hope you haven't used a lot of this black fabric as I am going to tell you to pull that stuff up and throw it away.  Check out on this site why it is so contraindicated to use landscape fabric/plastic for weed suppression.  Landscape fabric is to use beneath gravel to prevent loss of gravel down into the soil.  It should never be used as 'weed barrier'!!  They call it weed fabric to sell it.  Solarization is different and temporary.

Comment: @stormy gravel is going down in a couple of weeks. Black fabric has been down some time just because the ground really hardens up this time of year.

Comment: Doesn't matter.  You've probably got quite a bit of clay. Clay are the smallest particles in the soil pyramid and they are FLAT.  These particles are highly electrostatic.  That is why they use clay soil in concrete.  All soil is great soil just need to understand how to manage YOUR soil.  The ONLY WAY to improve any soil is by ADDING DECOMPOSED ORGANIC MATTER.  No other addition is warranted nor will anything else improve the aeration, nutrient composition, drainage for clay than DOG.  My own acronym.  Double digging with a shovel, turning it over adding DOM as one digs is the best way.

Comment: No more manipulation of clay soil!  Just break up clods with shovel and at the end dump DOM on top of the soil.  Soil organisms eat DOM they are unable to use NON DOM.  They eat it and take it back down into the soil and poop it out mixing it in the best way possible.  This is HUGE.  The more organisms the faster the mixing.  Allow plant beds to be 6-12" and even more off the level of your lawn.  That plastic STOPS this entire process.  Leaves and other normal matter decomposes and can then improve your soil.  That plastic screws up even the smallest semblance of an ecosystem!!

Comment: It is this DOM that will soften and make your soil more friable as well as other attributes to include chemicals and organisms necessary for plant health.  I had to charge clients to get rid of that stuff. If they were set (rarely after talking with me) on keeping that crap, I'd just tell them to go find someone else!  My reputation for health of landscapes was far more important than a client insisting they were right.  Customers are not always right especially when they don't have any knowledge of botany/biology of the outdoor world.  I educated constantly, to include some bosses...honest.

Comment: Before putting down the gravel (I suggest trying to find 3/8 minus looks better and easier to walk on than 5/8 minus), you should have the area excavated 4" below the surface.  NOW the landscape fabric is critical to use.  If the gravel area is adjacent to plant beds or lawn areas edge with PT 2X4's or Treks to have to top of the 2X4 level with the surface and not above.  Use stakes and SCREWS not nails, to secure then add 4" of gravel and compact.  Do not use pea gravel in this application, it needs to be angular crushed gravel or granite as small as you can find.  Score for curves with wood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Jasminum nudiflorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasminum_nudiflorum) or "Winter Jasmine".

"Winter jasmine is a slender, deciduous shrub native to China. It is widely cultivated as an ornamental and is reportedly naturalized in France and in scattered locations in the United States."

General Care: [Fine Gardening](http://www.finegardening.com/winter-jasmine-jasminum-nudiflorum) and [Royal Horticulture Society](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/details?plantid=1061).

Winter jasmine is best pruned in spring, immediately after flowering. Flowers develop on the previous year's growth. Pruning after flowering gives the new growth time to mature and flower next season.

[image]

[image]